# Ubuntu Phone SimpleHTTPServer python

Tags: python, ubuntu-touch

It is possible to use the module in Python SimpleHTTPServer on my Ubuntu Phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Touch only ships with Python 3. The module `SimpleHTTPServer` is one of the modules that has been renamed and/or moved for more consistency in the standard library.

That said, you can run the following command:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

I can't guarentee this will work on Ubuntu Touch though, this is just the normal way to do it.